# if condition of in_array to boolean

Tags: php, arrays, string, boolean

So I have an in_array check, called

```
if (in_array('pageLevel',$userlevels))
```

Which I want to connect to a boolean, like `$hasAccess` so I can apply

```
if ($hasAccess == true) { do something }
```

I tried `if (in_array('pageLevel',$userlevels)) { $hasAccess == true }`

but that does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me how to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $hasAccess == true

Should be `$hasAccess = true`.  Or

```
$hasAccess = in_array('pageLevel',$userlevels);
```

Comment: if (in_array('pageLevel',$userlevels)) { $hasAccess = true; } 
    
    
    if ($hasAccess) { dosomething }

works like a charm! Thanks guys, I was indeed mixing up the operators.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$hasAccess = true;` You need to assign to the variable (`=`), rather than just compare it (`==`) and throw the result away.